# scaladoc for Play! Framework with Scala module

Tags: scala, playframework, sbt, scaladoc

I'm a bit stumped as to how to run scaladoc on a Play! framework project.  It seems there are a lot of intricacies to account for, and I'm not having success.

Is there a tutorial I am missing?  Do you need to add in sbt or a build tool to make it reasonable?

Comment: Do you mean that haven't run Scaladoc on any project or that you have a specific problem because of Play? I think you'll probably need to clarify how you're currently building your project and generating the docs and what specific problems you're coming across. If you're using sbt it is just a matter of running the `doc` command, so that's certainly pretty easy.

Comment: Playframework 2.0 uses SBT to build your project. What version of play did you use ? Did you try to run `doc` task in play console ?

Comment: It's a specific problem because of Play.  Versions before 2.0 don't use sbt and I'm not sure how to set everything up to run scaladoc manually.

Comment: 1.2.4 with Scala module.  It has a javadoc command but no others.  I tried replicating the javadoc command but replacing it with scaladoc.  No luck so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came up with a solution that works, but not perfect.  You need to run the app to generate the Scala code for the templates.  Then run 'play scaladoc' with the code below.

Add 'play/framework/pym/play/commands/scaladoc.py' with contents:

```
import os, os.path
import shutil
import subprocess

from play.utils import *

COMMANDS = ['scaladoc', 'sd']

HELP = {
    'scaladoc': 'Generate your application scaladoc'
}

def execute(**kargs):
    command = kargs.get("command")
    app = kargs.get("app")
    args = kargs.get("args")
    play_env = kargs.get("env")

    app.check()
    modules = app.modules()
    if not os.environ.has_key('SCALA_HOME'):
        scaladoc_path = "scaladoc"
    else:
        scaladoc_path = os.path.normpath("%s/bin/scaladoc" % os.environ['SCALA_HOME'])

    fileList = []
    def add_scala_files(app_path):
        for root, subFolders, files in os.walk(os.path.join(app_path, 'app')):
            for file in files:
                if file.endswith(".scala"):
                    fileList.append(os.path.join(root, file))
        for root, subFolders, files in os.walk(os.path.join(app_path,
            'tmp/generated')):
            for file in files:
                if file.endswith(".scala"):
                    fileList.append(os.path.join(root, file))
    add_scala_files(app.path)
    for module in modules:
        add_scala_files(os.path.normpath(module))
    outdir = os.path.join(app.path, 'scaladoc')
    sout = open(os.path.join(app.log_path(), 'scaladoc.log'), 'w')
    serr = open(os.path.join(app.log_path(), 'scaladoc.err'), 'w')
    if (os.path.isdir(outdir)):
        shutil.rmtree(outdir)
    scaladoc_cmd = [scaladoc_path, '-classpath', app.cp_args(), '-d', outdir] + args + fileList
    print "Generating scaladoc in " + outdir + "..."
    subprocess.call(scaladoc_cmd, env=os.environ, stdout=sout, stderr=serr)
    print "Done! You can open " + os.path.join(outdir, 'overview-tree.html') + " in your browser."
```

Answer (score 2):

In a Project with Playframework 2.2.0 just use this commands:

```
clean
doc
```

The Answer of doc is (only if you use clean) i.E.

Main Scala API documentation to .../myproject/target/scala-2.10/api...
Then open index.html in this folder.

If you search all tasks just type in:

```
tasks -V
```